# What is the reason why (sample) Pearson correlation coefficient stands for a linear relationship?

Tags: calculus, statistics

In a Data Analysis book I am starting to read, the author makes reference to the (sample) Pearson correlation coefficient and introduces the formula:

$r(x,y)=\frac{\sum^{n}\mathop{_{i=1}}(x_{i}-\boldsymbol{x})(y_{i}-\boldsymbol{y})}{(n-1)s_{x}s_{y}}$

where x and y in bold stand for the mean of the two respective values and sx and sy stand for the respective standard deviations.

The author emphasizes that the coefficient r is +1 where there is a perfect linear relationship between the two variables and the slope of the line on the scatter plot is positive, while r is -1 when there is a linear relationship with a negative slope.

What i do not understand is the correlation between the graphical representation of the scatter plot and the formula.

In particular, for the formula to be correct, should ìthe following biconditionals be true? How are they proved in order to show the fact that the formula gives the result $|1|$ iff there is a perfect linear relationship between x and y?

$r(x,y)=1$ if and only if the data points arranged in the respective scatter plot form a straight line with positive slope

$r(x,y)=-1$ if and only if the data points arranged in the respective scatter plot form a straight line with positive slope

Book is Michael R. Berthold, Christian Borgelt, Frank Höppner, Frank Klawonn - Guide to Intelligent Data Analysis_ How to Intelligently Make Sense of Real Data-Springer (2010) page 60.

Comment: That $|r(x,y)|\le1$ comes from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The edge cases $r(x,y)=\pm1$ come from the equality case in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: This answer gives an overview. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160629/relationship-between-correlation-and-linear-dependency
The correlation being $\pm 1$ implies that $Var(X-cY) = 0$ which implies that they are linearly related.

Comment: One can also interpret $r(x,y)$ as the cosine of the angle between $x$ and $y$. The measure of the angle is positive in case of positive correlation (and extremal when $\cos=1$), and negative otherwise (extremal when $\cos=-1$).